# How JQuery could extend an element with another one containing event handlers?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, extend

Is there a solution to create a dummy element with its properties, methods and event handlers and extend an existing element with it ?
For example :

```
var dummyElement = $('<div />', {
  // properties
  ...
  // methods
  ...
  // event handlers
  ...
});
```

and then,

```
$.extend( $('#myElement'), dummyElement );
```

Now, $('#myElement') has the dummyElement's properties, methods and event handlers, in addition to its own.

Is it possible? How could I do that with JQuery ?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see what is happening!

Comment: I did it, but (perhaps because the syntax is incorrect) it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to the different answers, particularly from *Lee*.
It seems that the `$.extend(...)` jQuery method is not designed to extend a DOM element from another one. But it can extend a DOM element from an object. Here is a solution to do that :

1) First I create the extension objects. Each of these extensions must have an `initExtension()` method defined. Here is an example for creating two extension objects :

```
var myObjExtension1 = {
  // constructor
  initExtension : function() {
    // Add some data properties
    this.something = 'something';

    // Add some method properties
    this.doSomething = function() { alert(this.something); };

    // Add some DOM elements
    $(this).append('<div>element created from extension 1</div>');  

    // Add some event handlers
    $(this).click(
      function(evt) {
        $(this).append('<div>element created from extension 1 click event</div>');
      }
    );
  }
};

var myObjExtension2 = {
  // constructor
  initExtension : function() {
    // Add some data properties
    this.more = 'more';

    // Add some method properties
    this.doMore = function() { alert(this.more); };

    // Add some DOM elements
    $(this).append('<div>element created from extension 2</div>');  

    // Add some event handlers
    $(this).click(
      function(evt) {
        $(this).append('<div>element created from extension 2 click event</div>');
      }
    );
  }
};
```

2) In order to extend easily all the elements I need to extend, I created a little jQuery plug-in. This plug-in contains one method that extend the source element with the specified extension:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.extendWith = function( objExtension ) {
    this.each( 
      function(index) {
        $.extend( this, objExtension );
        this.initExtension();
      }
    );
    return this; // jQuery chaining
  }
})(jQuery);
```

3) Finally, I extend some jQuery elements. Note that in the following example, I extend the elements that match the `someElement` class, first with the `myObjExtension1` and then with the `myObjExtension2`, by chaining the `extendWith(...)` plug-in method:

```
$('.someElement').extendWith( myObjExtension1 ).extendWith( myObjExtension2 );
```

Now, all the `myObjExtension1` and `myObjExtension2` data properties, method properties and event handlers are available from my $('.someElement') elements. Example:

```
$('.someElement').each( function() {
  this.doSomething();
  this.doMore();
});
```

Comment: The use of `$.extend` in your jQuery plugin isn't necessary.  It results in your "initExtension" method being copied to the element itself, which you probably *don't* want.  A simpler approach would be to remove the `$.extend`, and change the call to initExtension as follows:  `objExtension.initExtension.call(this)`.  That will call `initExtension()` with `this` set to the element (same as your code), but it does so without copying `initExtension` onto the element.

Comment: Another observation: your "extension" duplicates same design pattern provided by the jQuery plugin architecture. When you call a plugin function on a jQuery element-set, the plugin function is called with the element-set as `this`.  Typical plugins then change or add-to (i.e. "extend") the elements in the set.  This may include adding/removing child elements, event handlers, and/or setting properties, attributes, and css values.  Your "Obj Extension" just adds another layer of abstraction above this:  a jQuery plugin that applies "extension functions", which could themselves be jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't need a dummy element at all. In following example I demonstrates a simple way to create an element in pure javascript.

**Source Code**

```
createElement: function (options) {
    /// <summary>Creates a document object model (DOM) element.</summary>
    /// <param name="options" type="Object">An object that contains tag name, attributes, events, properties and children.</param>

    var clone = this.extend({}, options);

    // Create element
    var e = document.createElement(clone.tag);
    delete clone.tag;

    // Assign attributes
    if (clone.attributes) {

        for (var attrib in clone.attributes) {
            e.setAttribute(attrib.replace('$', ''), clone.attributes[attrib]);
        }

        delete clone.attributes;
    }

    // Create and append children if has
    if (clone.children) {

        for (var idx in clone.children) {
            e.appendChild(this.createElement(clone.children[idx]));
        }

        delete clone.children;
    }

    // Assign event handlers
    if (clone.events) {

        for (var en in clone.events) {

            var handler = clone.events[en];

            if (handler instanceof Function)
                this.addHandler(e, en, handler);
        }

        delete clone.events
    }

    // Assign properties
    for (var prop in clone) {
        e[prop] = clone[prop];
    }

    return e;

},

addHandler: function (element, eventName, handler) {

    // Firefox is first, Of cource after chrome :p
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
    }

},

extend: function (expando, properties, override) {

    if (properties && typeof (properties) == 'object') {

        for (var prop in properties) {

            var val = properties[prop];

            if (!expando[prop] || override)
                expando[prop] = val;

        }

    }

    return expando;

}
```

You can rewrite the above code with jQuery to extend your element, instead of creating a new one.

**Usage**

```
Util.createElement({
    tag: 'input',
    type: 'checkbox',
    checked: this.checked,
    events: {
        change: function(e) { // ... }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery's [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.  In conjunction with [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), I think you can accomplish something close to (but not exactly) what you're looking for:

```
// 1- create dummy
var dummy - $('<div />');

// 2- add stuff to dummy...
// ex: adding a click handler, and an "alt" attribute
dummy.click(function(evt) { console.log("click"); }
dummy.attr("alt", "this is the alt text for dummy");

// 3- clone dummy, and the replace `#myElement` with the clone
$('#myElement').replaceWith( dummy.clone(true) );
```

**Note**: the code you've used when creating `dummyElement` in your example, is not a valid form of the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function.  As far as I know, you can't add properties, methods, and handlers by just passing them as a second argument to the jQuery function.  If you do pass a second argument, jQuery will interpret this as a context in which to resolve the selector. I've shown an example of adding a click handler, and an attribute.

---

**Edit**: If you're just trying to copy object properties (as you said: "properties", "methods", and "event handlers") from one HTML Element to another, then `$.extend(...)` is the tool for the job.  Just be sure you're operating on the HTML Elements themselves, not the Jquery set objects.  That'll look something like this:

```
var dummy = $('<div />');
var myElement = $('#myElement');
$.extend(myElement.get(0), dummy.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks Lee, but the result of your code is a new element replacing the existing one, and this is not what i'm looking for. The existing element already has classes and attributes. Also, I would like to add some behaviors (properties, methods and event handlers) to the existing element, from several different elements.

Comment: Well, `$.extend(A, B)` does exactly that.  It copies all properties (and methods) from `B` onto `A`.  Perhaps your problem is that you're trying to operate on jquery sets, when you intend to operate on the elements themselves.  Try:  `$.extend($('#myElement').get(0), dummy.get(0))`

Comment: When I use $.extend() on the elements (i.e., with .get(0)), I have an JQuery error : NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: DOM Exception 7: An attempt was made to modify an object where modifications are not allowed.

Comment: That's not a "jQuery Error", it's a DOM error.  It happens when you attempt to modify a read only property of a DOM object.  For example: `outerHTML` is a readonly property of HTMLElement. Of course your `dummy` div will contain a property, 'outerHTML', and `$.extend()` will dutifully try to copy it over to your `myElement` div - this triggers the error.  You can use a for/in loop to run through and copy the properties of dummy yourself - then you can see exactly where it's failing.  [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/A9uLw/) that shows that approach.

Comment: Thanks Lee. See my last answer where I explain a solution based on what you said in your comments. Have you got a better solution ?